# Surfaces of constant curvature using the conformal method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, symmetry

I'm doing a study of surfaces with constant curvature which leads to solving the equation:
$$\Delta\phi = -e^{2\phi}K_0$$
for a 2-dimensional metric with constant curvature such that rotation around the origin is an isometry ($\phi = \phi(r)$).
A first idea was using polar coordinates, and convert the equation to polar coordinates:
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d\phi}{dr} + \frac{d^2\phi}{dr} = -e^{2\phi(r)}K_0$$
Which is a second order nonlinear ordinary differential equation.
I've used Maple and Mathematica to solve this equation but I'm not happy with the solution, it's quite complicated (Bessel function).

Does anyone have any idea about how to solve the first equation maybe simplifying the procedure with some properties of isometries?

Thanks.

Comment: @John: let's close the old as a dupe of the new. This one has (now) better tags.

Comment: @WillieWong: Looks like "pde" drives you here? I am more happy with the "dg" tags though.

Comment: @John: no, I put in the PDE tag actually. Perhaps you can replace surfaces with dg if you prefer. There were some bad tags before (differential field, for example) which I removed. Personally I would classify this as inherently a rg question not a dg one, but I understand opinions can differ.

Comment: But the PDE can be seen from a viewpoint of differential fields, which is what interests me... I don't want a classical interpretation.

Comment: **If** you actually want to to look at this nonlinear ODE from the perspective of differential fields, you should make it absolutely clear in your question that's what you want. There is zero indication right now in the question statement that says anything to that effect. For that matter, then, there's rather little point of introducing the geometry to the problem to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply through by $r$ and note that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dr}\left( r \frac{d \phi}{dr}\right) = \frac{d \phi}{dr}+r\frac{d^{2} \phi}{d r^{2}}
\end{equation}
Then you're left with
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dr}\left( r \frac{d \phi}{dr}\right)=-r e^{2 \phi} K_{0}
\end{equation}

Comment: I am not exactly sure how this is supposed to help?